# Is it possible to install zerotier-one inside a Docker container and deploy it to heroku?

Tags: docker, heroku, dockerfile, zerotier

I have an app that I have successfully deployed to Heroku. however, the app requires a connection to the user (me) and I'm behind a firewall. so I thought I will install Zerotier VPN alongside my app and use that to do the communication.

the problem is in order to install Zerotier on a Docker container I need to pass the --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN and --cap-add=NET_ADMIN flags to the container and I don't know where to specify these arguments on Heroku